# How to combine two NameValueCollections?

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I have two NameValueCollections:

```
NameValueCollection customTag = (NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("secureAppSettings");
NameValueCollection appSetting = (NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings");
```

I tried `customTag.Add(appSetting);` method but I get this error: `Collection is read-only.`

How would I combine them to one, so i can access all the elements from both?

Comment: What do you want to do if they both have the same key value?

Comment: They should overwrite.

Comment: Which should overwrite?

Comment: The one that is added should overwrite the original. In this case appSetting should overwrite customTag.

Comment: Given the exception message, it seems you will have to create a new, writeable `NameValueCollection` and copy all the elements into that. Note that you will have to iterate yourself, calling the `NameValueCollection.Set()` method, as the default behavior of `NameValueCollection` is to append the added value to the list of existing values, not to overwrite them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To combine the collections, try something like the following:

```
var secureSettings = (NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("secureAppSettings");
var appSettings = (NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

// Initialise a new NameValueCollection with the contents of the secureAppSettings section
var allSettings = new NameValueCollection(secureSettings);
// Add the values from the appSettings section
foreach (string key in appSettings)
{
    // Overwrite any entry already there
    allSettings[key] = appSettings[key];
}
```

Use the new `allSettings` collection to access the combined settings.

Comment: How does this handle array-like Query String parameters?

Comment: @palswim I hadn't tested that specifically. Is there an example you can give me which isn't working?

Comment: What if you dont want to overwrite but merge/combine?

Comment: Hi, @TimSchmelter. You can use the Add method to merge NameValueCollections without replacing what is already there. Values with the same key are combined into comma-separated strings. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.add?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 6):

> I tried `customTag.Add(appSetting);` method but I get this error: `Collection is read-only.`

This means the `customTag` object is read only, and can't be written to. `.Add` attempts to modify the original `NameValueCollection`. `System.Configuration` contains a `ReadOnlyNameValueCollection` that extends `NameValueCollection` to make it read only, and so despite casting to the generic `NameValueCollection`, the object is still read only.

> How would I combine them to one, so i can access all the elements from both?

All you need is to add both collections to a third writable `NameValueCollection`.

Given:

```
var customTag = (NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("secureAppSettings");
var appSetting = (NameValueCollection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings");
```

You could `.Add` both:

```
var collection = new NameValueCollection();
collection.Add(customTag);
collection.Add(appSettings);
```

However, the `NameValueCollection` constructor has a shorthand that calls `Add` internally:

```
var collection = new NameValueCollection(customTag);
collection.Add(appSettings);
```

---

Be aware, that in both cases, using `Add` will allow multiple values to be added to each key.

For example, if you were to merge `{foo: "bar"}` and `{foo: "baz"}` the result would be `{foo: ["bar", "baz"]}` (JSON syntax used for brevity).

Comment: I was wondering about this! Much cleaner than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by [zzzzBov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000311/3613932) is complete. However, if you want to merge multiple NameValueCollection or not modify any of the original ones, you can consider the following method which merges an arbitrary number of `NameValueCollection`.

**Code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Merges the specified NameValueCollection arguments into a single NamedValueCollection.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="args">An array of NameValueCollection to be merged.</param>
/// <returns>Merged NameValueCollection</returns>
/// <remarks>
/// Returns an empty collection if args passed are null or empty.
/// </remarks>
static NameValueCollection Merge(params NameValueCollection[] args)
{
    NameValueCollection combined = new NameValueCollection();

    if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
    {
        return combined;
    }

    NameValueCollection current = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        current = args[i];

        if (current != null && current.Count > 0)
        {
            combined.Add(current);
        }
    }

    return combined;
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
NameValueCollection northAmericaCollection = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "Cananda", "Ottawa" },
    { "USA", "Washington, D.C." },
    { "Mexico", "Mexico City" }
};

NameValueCollection southAmericaCollection = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "Argentina", "Buenos Aires" },
    { "Peru", "Lima" },
    { "Chile", "Santiago" }
};

NameValueCollection merged = Merge(northAmericaCollection, null, southAmericaCollection, null);

for (int i = 0; i < merged.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", merged.GetKey(i), merged.Get(i));
}

// The example displays the following output:
//      Name: Cananda, Value: Ottawa
//      Name: USA, Value: Washington, D.C.
//      Name: Mexico, Value: Mexico City
//      Name: Argentina, Value: Buenos Aires
//      Name: Peru, Value: Lima
//      Name: Chile, Value: Santiago
```

The method is also robust enough to withstand `Merge(null)` or `Merge()`, and simply return an empty `NameValueCollection`. This will ensure your code does not throw exceptions because of bad input.

Comment: What happens with duplicate keys which is the interesting part of the Merge method?